# When i finish the mission (Copy Protection) in Prey why cant i craft nuromods

Tags: ps4, prey

I already beat the game once and when I started a brand new game it immediately said I couldn't craft any more neuro mods. (even though I had crafted approximately 0)
now I've completed the quest copy protection but every fabrication station says no licenses remaining but it no longer pops up the error message that is displayed on the fabricator. So i still cant craft any more. PLZ HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset Neuromod licenses on Halden Graves's terminal.

Comment: I do that and it just says no licenses remaining

Comment: Are you sure you select proper option in Utilities menu?

Comment: well there are 3 options lock doors , unlock doors and reset licenses so yeah I pick the right one.